# Was the renewed Captain Scarlet a clone of the original?

Tags: captain-scarlet

[Captain Scarlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Scarlet_%28character%29) dies and is resurrected as a Mysteron agent. Later, the *"real"* Captain Scarlet personality reasserts itself and Scarlet becomes one of the *good guys*, but now indestructible.

My question: is this the *original* Captain Scarlet or an identical clone with the same personality, essentially a new person?

Ideally the best answer will cover both the [original series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Scarlet_and_the_Mysterons) and the [new series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerry_Anderson%27s_New_Captain_Scarlet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the original Captain Scarlet, the resurrected version was clearly a new individual, as can be seen in the [first episode](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xftu7i_captain-scarlet-01-the-mysterons-pilot-1-3_shortfilms) when the new Captain Scarlet hides the body of the original.

However, in the [first episode of New Captain Scarlet](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvOlzOsZEi0), the implication is that Captain Scarlet is altered (he doesn't die before the Mysterons take over him).

Answer (score 2):

**Paul Metcalfe, Captain Scarlet, age 32, died at the hands of the Mysterons in the very first episode of the series. He is not a clone but a [retro-metabolized replicant](http://captainscarlet.wikia.com/wiki/Retro-metabolism), with the power to return to life if killed.** This power is very handy for a character with a penchant for being killed over the course of his adventures.

> Captain Scarlet's Mysteronised body, like those of all Mysteron likenesses, is still vulnerable to electricity and impervious to X-rays. He also has a "sixth sense" when in the presence of a strong Mysteron influence - he becomes nauseated, sweats, and suffers a severe headache - but this sense sometimes does not indicate all Mysteron presences in an area. Though Captain Scarlet "dies" several times in the course of the series - usually quite violently - he always returns to life. --[Wikipedia > Captain Scarlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Scarlet_%28character%29)

This replicated body thinks, acts and believes itself to be Paul Metcalfe and is treated as such by his comrades. It was never supposed to remember who or what it was, so the process used by the Mysterons must create a perfect duplicate, memories and all, and then suppresses them. This allows their agent to think, act and behave as the original but serve as their perfect spy.

> The Mysterons: Alien nemesis of Spectrum, from the planet Mars. They have the power of retrometabolism, which means they can kill a person and rebuild them as a weapon under their control. [Wikipedia > New Captain Scarlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerry_Anderson%27s_New_Captain_Scarlet)

[image: Captain Scarlet]

**Answering comment:** Yours is a question of philosophy not physics. The man as we know him is dead. This perfect copy replicates all that could be known about him, except he is not made of the same stuff of men. He is now comprised of an alien technology.

However, he is the equivalent of himself. Equivalent as defined:

- Having similar or identical effects.
- Being essentially equal, all things considered

He looks like a man, sounds like one, believes himself to be one. **But he is not.** He is a copy of Paul Metcalfe. **But a difference that isn't a difference, is it really different?**

**Define soul?** Since we cannot see it, or weigh it, can it really matter in answering this question? If your question is one of theology and assumes that the soul and the body are as one, then this man has died and his soul has migrated onward. This body is a high quality replica, essentially soul-less by the religious standards most societies use.

Personally, I would disagree. If he is willing to fight and die (again and again) then it does not matter if he has a soul or not. Justice has a near-immortal champion and Team Good is ahead of the curve, for a change.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how this answers the question. Is this then a **copy** or the original person, or *soul*, in a new body?

Comment: Again, thanks, but I wasn't planning to start a debate about the nature of a soul, it was just a convenient word; *consciousness* would also work. And does it matter if he is an exact copy? Well, it would to him, and probably to those close to him.

Answer (score -2):

I always rationalised it as the Mysterions making a mistake and that the original Captain Scarlet was not dead when he was remade ("...but first, they must destroy."). You can clearly see both after the crash that - eventually - kills the original (by bleeding to death?), before the copy returns to Cloudbase. The copy was therefore, I suggest, not free of the original's *personality*, which was able to reassert itself.

Perhaps this why they need to destroy living beings/people, as the rest of the replication is just a function of (material and) tissues, including memories? These would indeed be human tissues, or simple tests would reveal non-human agents.

Note that the 'question of philosophy' totally ignores all other Mysterion agents who, although likewise invulnerable, remain agents.

I've not seen the new series so can't comment on anything in there.

Comment: The only relevant information provided in this answer is the fact that the original Scarlet's body is shown alongside his duplicate after the car crash in the first episode, and that information was already provided over a decade ago by the two previous answers. The majority of this post is a tangential commentary, seemingly inspired in part by [Thaddeus Howze's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/20346/122024), rather than a direct answer to the question itself.